# Django Template: remove the buttons when session starts

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make a Login Authentication in Django. I have made sign in and sign up buttons in the upper navbar.

Now What I need to achieve is when I sign in to the application the redirection would take place and at that time session is checked and if the session has started then the sign in and sign up button disappears and the User ABC button comes at its place.

I am trying to do this with my code snipped here it is.

```
{% if request.session.loggedin %}
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#"><b>Hello Chitrank</b></a></li>
{% else %}
     <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a></li> 
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#signin"><b>Sign In</b></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Please suggest me what to do , Am i using a wrong way to check the session or if there is some other way to do this then the solution is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

is what you are looking for. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth

also allows you to do this

```
<span>Welcome back {{ user.username }}!</span>
```

Comment: It still not working is it because I am using `{% include './django_component_include/header.html' %}` in my index.html page

Comment: Thank you knightZeRo the snippet worked for me , and rest I cutomize my login view.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution on this, based on the logged in user (requires that you use django build in auth system).
You may access `request.user.is_authenticated` in your template and differentiate on its state (True is loggend in).

Comment: I am using `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in my template for checking for signned in users under session, but When I log in to this even then I get signin and signup buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether you're logged in in the corresponding view and pass variable `current_user` to your template, then check:

```
    {% if current_user %}
        Hello, {{current_user.name}}
    {% else %}
        {# ... Display signin and signup buttons #}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: As per you say I have updated my views.py file and as my views.py were 
`existing_user = User.objects.authenticate(**form.cleaned_data)` also I referenced a variable `siteuser=existing_user` and returned the response as
`return render(request,'index.html',{'siteuser':siteuser})` but no effect on my template after signin.